# how to run freeradius using docker-compose

Tags: docker, freeradius

Could you advise how to make run freeradius using dockercompose?

Compose file here which is stop automatically in a sec.

```yaml
    version: '3'

    services:

        freeradius:
          image: freeradius/freeradius-server
          restart: always
          volumes:
            - ./freeradius:/etc/freeradius
          ports:
            - "1812-1813:1812-1813/udp"

    volumes:
      freeradius:
```

But when I run it with docker directly, then it runs

```
docker run --name my-radius -i -t freeradius/freeradius-server /bin/bash
```

In here, it display configuration file,

```
root@945f7bcb3520:/# ls /etc/freeradius

README.rst  clients.conf  experimental.conf  huntgroups      mods-config   panic.gdb  
proxy.conf    sites-available  templates.conf  users
certs       dictionary    hints              mods-available  mods-enabled  policy.d   
radiusd.conf  sites-enabled    trigger.conf
```

but then volume folder, ./freeradius don't include any conf file.

So, how can make it work properly in general?

Answer (score 1):

You don't display your Dockerfile here. But I can guess that you are running a command in the Dockerfile that doesn't persist. It works from the command line, because /bin/bash will persist until you exit.

I have had this problem a couple times recently.

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten a similar setup up and running with my config being loaded. All my configuration has been done according to the docker hub documentation. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` for reference.

(I am aware that I could probably avoid the Dockerfile completely, but the advantage of this is that the Dockerfile is basically 1:1 to the official documentation..)

run `docker-compose up -d` to run it. Both files should be in the parent directory of raddb

[image: folder structure]

### Dockerfile

```
FROM freeradius/freeradius-server:latest
COPY raddb/ /etc/raddb/

EXPOSE 1812 1813
```

### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '2.2'
services:
  freeradius:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: freeradius
    ports:
      - "1812-1813:1812-1813/udp"
    restart: always
```

Comment: The big difference to user6508956's approach is, that he doesn't build his own container copying his configuration into it, but rather uses the original container trying to map his configuration into it.

Answer (score 1):

Your command to run the container directly

```
docker run --name my-radius -i -t freeradius/freeradius-server /bin/bash
```

is not equivalent to your dockercompose setup.

You are not mounting the config directory (also you are not publishing the container ports to the host - this will prevent you from accessing freeradius from outside a container).

I assume if you run your docker container mounting the volume

```
docker run --name my-radius -v ./freeradius:/etc/freeradius -i -t freeradius/freeradius-server /bin/bash
```

it will not work either.

For me, it didn't work when I tried to replace the whole config directory with a volume mount.
I had to mount components of the configuration individually. E.g.

```
-v ./freeradius/clients.conf:/etc/freeradius/clients.conf
```

Apparently, when you replace the whole directory something fails when starting freeradius. Excerpt from radius.log when mounting the whole config directory:

```
Fri Jan 13 10:49:22 2023 : Info: Debug state unknown (cap_sys_ptrace capability not set)
Fri Jan 13 10:49:22 2023 : Info: systemd watchdog is disabled
Fri Jan 13 10:49:22 2023 : Error: rlm_preprocess: Error reading /etc/freeradius/mods-config/preprocess/huntgroups
Fri Jan 13 10:49:22 2023 : Error: /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/preprocess[13]: Instantiation failed for module "preprocess"
```

Comment: This is exactly right and exactly the problem I had been facing. You cannot map the entire /etc/raddb or /etc/freeradius to a host volume mount. I suspect that is because of the symlinks that are used for key configuration files like "user".